# awk multiple commands or other suggestions

Tags: awk, sed, grep, bioinformatics

I have a file that looks like this:

[image: file]

The stuff that I am interested in is **locus_tag="*"** and % of **Identity** (100%, 91%, 60%,..).

I was thinking of commands

`awk '/locus_tag/{print $3}' test` and `awk '/Identities/{print $4}' test`

How can I combine them?

Comment: Please share data as plain text and **not** as images.

Comment: You can have multiple pairs of pattern-action, so you can join your commands into `awk '/locus_tag/{print $3}/Identities/{print $4}' test`

Comment: how small or large is the file ? i have different approaches in mind

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with concise, testable sample input, expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you further. See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples.

Answer (score 0):

**SYNOPSIS**

completely hands-free driving by leveraging `FS` as main driver of everything :

- the idea is to avoid hard-coding in field numbers if possible,
  preferring flexible regex instead to deal with variability in input data

  ```
  - (i've noticed "locus tag" has been spelt both Locus and locus in the example)
  ```
- the code is even simpler if not for the final bit about fixing the space `" "` with underscore `"_"`

**CODE**

```
{m,g}awk '($(!(NF*=!_<NF))~"^[\"(]")*(sub("^[ \t]*","")+sub(" ","_"))' \
          OFS=                 \
           FS='^.*(Identities[ ]?[=][^(]*|[Ll]ocus[ _]tag[ ]?[=][^\42]*)|[,][ ].*$'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
"2-180_02899"
(100%)
"5-92_00077"
(91%)
"PoryDSM17970_00031"
(60%)
"PbryCz1a_00993"
(61%)
"PpalDSM17968_02227"
```

An alternate approach without underscore fixing would be like

```
mawk '$!_=$_=$(NF=3+!(NF*=/([Ll]ocus tag|Identities)[ ]?[=]/))' \
              OFS=  FS='[,\t=()]+'

"2-180 02899"
100%
"5-92 00077"
91%
"PoryDSM17970 00031"
60%
"PbryCz1a 00993"
61%
"PpalDSM17968 02227"
```